# Is it possible to emulate windows 10 machine as a usb slave through type-c connector?

Tags: usb, libusb, usb-drive

I am wondering if it is possible to emulate a windows 10 pc as a usb slave (client device) through a type-c connector when connecting to another PC/MAC(or even a cell phone), to be a usb storage device or HID etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows PC as a USB slave to emulate a thumbdrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682193/windows-pc-as-a-usb-slave-to-emulate-a-thumbdrive)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to have:

1. PC that has USB device mode controller
2. Windows 10 device mode driver - [this resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/usb-dual-role-driver-stack-architecture), should be good starting point for looking into this further.

Comment: There is a single line in the article you linked which completely ruins your theory - *Note Function drivers are not available on Windows 10 for desktop editions.*

Comment: As I wrote: 'would have to have' - this does not indicate it is currently possible, but that there would be possibility to do it, if the driver existed. And the article, as you cited, describes why it is not possible, at least until you write your own driver stack or Microsoft allow to use its drivers on Desktop edition of Windows.